# magento multi language storeview

Tags: magento-1.5, magento

I have just installed magento with 5 different languages. I created storeviews for 4 new languages. Now the problem is the Catalog and products are shown only in english. The arabic, russian and other languages view do not have products and catalog at all. In the manage Catalog, ALL STORE VIEWS is chosen. Can anyone guide me what I am missing to do?

Answer (score 0):

you need play with the scope of the configuration. This a comun error in Magento in the begining. You should go to the product configuration and select the correct scope in 
[image]

To configure diferent domain to diferent store to diferen de language thougth in the customer you need configure in sistem->configuration->web in 
[image]

and later you need load the correct virtual store view to the correct domain. You can configure this in :

```
  <VirtualHost *:80>
   DocumentRoot "C:\Program Files\Zend\Apache2/htdocs/local.pruebas.com"
   ServerName local.pruebas.es
   DirectoryIndex index.html index.php index.htm
   SetEnv MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE "1"
   SetEnv MAGE_RUN_CODE "store_es"
   SetEnv MAGE_RUN_TYPE "store" 
   <Directory "C:\Program Files\Zend\Apache2/htdocs/local.pruebas.com">
     AllowOverride All
      Options All
      Order allow,deny
      Allow from all
   </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

hope help you!!

Comment: It seems after reindexing the system, I can see the same catalog in different languages again. According your method, do I have to create for each storeview,  ServerName local.pruebas.es? I have tried it before but I could not make it work

Comment: you should load diferents store view depends trought the domain the customer go to your web. You ahoud create one serverName if you want diference by domain. Otherwise yo have a selector of view(language) in the top of the web to load de store view. You can see a example in Magento Sample data to inglish,french,germnany.